# Alert not working due to presentViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

Seems that calling an Alert in my UIViewController causes ploblems with the presentViewController (...due to probably inadvertently trying to present the same view controller twice in quick succession...).

What could I do against that issue (...see code below) ???

Error message :

```
<MyApp.MyViewController: 0x67544325620> which is already presenting (null)
```

The code :

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if (textField.text.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) > 5) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Only Initials with maximal 5 letters allowed!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        // that is where the problem seems to occur.... !!! Why ????
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: "not working" - in what way? what happens and what should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use this code exactly, please modify to fit your situation.  This is an example which may help you gain understanding and prevent your problem:

```
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Only Initials with maximal 5 letters allowed!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    // assuming that this is the first time your controller is presented

    println("is presenting \(presentedViewController)") //is nil

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //is now not nil
    println("is presenting \(presentedViewController)")        

    //something bad happened and your application is trying to present the alert again, safe guard against presenting it twice by checking if presentedViewController is nil or not
    if presentedViewController == nil {
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to present the Alert on top view controller (presentedViewController).

Comment: What do you mean by "on top" ??

Comment: if your are using 'navigationController' to push view controller, than you must present alert on top controller "which is on top in stack", or on 'presentedViewController' if your are presenting a view controller

Comment: I think my issue has more to do with the fact that my "textFieldShouldEndEditing" is called three times - most likely due to fact that my textField is created in code (...or for some reason). Therefore, the hint from Frankie helped me on short notive (i.e. if presentedViewController == nil {...}

Answer (score 0):

Try following Code to show UIAlertViewController

Call bellow line:

```
 [self showMessage:@"Message" withTitle:@"Title"];
```

Method:

```
  -(void)showMessage:(NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString *)title
    {
        UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                      message:message
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

            //do something when click button
        }];
        [alert addAction:okAction];
        [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```